# .NET exe file need to execute in .NEt 4

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I have an application developed in .NET 3.5. With PC's having .NET 4.0, this application doesnot execute at all. Application in all contains 2 dll's & 2 exe's (all developed by me).

I came to know that .NET4.0 is not backward compatible, due to which this problem is arised. Now, how do I make my application running on PC with .NET4.0 or 4.5. I just installed VS2010 (have VS2008) & want to know what & how to do to make the applicaiton execute in PC's with .net <= 3.5 & >= 4.0 ? I have not yet compiled or executed my application created under 3.5 after installing VS2010.

Do I need to have 2 apps' 1 for 3.5 & 1 for higher .net versions ?

Need your guidance....

Thanks

Comment: May I ask what's the reason to target an older framework? Why not just use 4.0 and throw 3.5 and below altogether? otherwise you will have to compile 2 versions (or as many versions as different framework versions you expect to support)

Comment: @HighCore: I don't know about OPs environment, but in most corporate env. it's a PITA to get software installed, even if it means just an update to something existing. not sure OPs purpose, but may be running in to situations where they _have_ to support older versions.

Comment: @BradChristie Yes, their is a need to support .net4.0 also now. Till now with net3.5, things were running smooth. Now they want same app to run on .net 4.0 also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to maintain two versions:

- One for >= .NET 4
- One for < .NET 4

Typically, you would create one branch for the .NET 4 version and one branch for the version for the older frameworks.

The branch for .NET 4 would be the branch you add new features to.
The branch for the older frameworks would not receive any new features to encourage people to move to .NET 4. This branch would only receive critical updates like major bug fixes or fixes for security vulnerabilities.

Comment: "[...] with the exception of security patches." But agreed, good purpose for branching.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, Thanks Daniel. Your idea of branching is really good. Just in case the client doesn't agree, then in my 3.5 app, if I add <supportedRuntime> element, then for it to run on 4.0, do I need to provide any thing more like dll's of 3.5 or so. With the supportedRuntime element, will the same app run on any .net - <= 3.5 or >= 4.0 ?

Comment: @BradChristie, Can u please clarify, what you mean by "[...] with the exception of security patches.". I didn't get ur point.

Comment: @Tvd: What Brad meant is explained in the last paragraph of my answer. About your other comment: You gotta test this, there might be some other differences, but in principal, that should be it.